# How to executing cron one minute after midnight every day?

Tags: unix, cron

I want to execute cron every day on midnight at time 00:01 Hrs.
Is the following cron time correct?

```
1 0 * * * *
```

Comment: Yes @Nishant this is correct, For more info, you can rever 

https://crontab.guru/#1_0_*_*_*

Comment: Thanks @Abhinavbhardwaj

Answer (score 20):

Yes the cron time is correct.

```
1 0 * * * /mydir/myscript
```

should be your cron entry.

Each cron entry consists of six fields, in the following order:

```
minute(s) hour(s) day(s) month(s) weekday(s) command(s)
 0-59      0-23    1-31    1-12     0-6
```

Comment: @Abhinavbhardwaj I have tried this & it works. Thanks Natarajan

Answer (score 5):

`1 0 * * * /mydir/myscript` <-- Correct 1 minute after midnight

`1 0 * * * *`  <--- Incorrect, Syntax Error

Answer (score -1):

`0 1 0 * * ?`

or

`1 0 * * *`

You can generate crons example with https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Answer (score -2):

Let's get the definitions straight: cron is a daemon that is designed to run continuously and execute commands at specified intervals when you tell it to.

To do that, it needs two things: an interval and a command.

Your example has a valid interval, but is missing a command to execute one minute after midnight:

```
1 0 * * * * /path/to/executable/or/script/here
```